# Update property value sub objects that match a filter

Tags: jq

For example in JavaScript:

```js
list.map(z => {if (z.Action.Charge > 0) { z.Action.Charge = 1;} return z;)
```

The closest I've got in `jq` is

```bash
cat list | jq '.values  = .values  | if ( .value.Action.Charge == 0 ) then ( .value.Action.Charge = 1 ) else . end'
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Input

```json
[
  {
    "Action": {
      "Charge": 21,
      "Discharge": 100
    },
    "T": "2023-10-05T01:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "Action": {
      "Charge": 0,
      "Discharge": 22
    },
    "T": "2023-10-05T04:00:00Z"
  }
]
```

Required output

```json
[
  {
    "Action": {
      "Charge": 34,
      "Discharge": 100
    },
    "T": "2023-10-05T01:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "Action": {
      "Charge": 0,
      "Discharge": 22
    },
    "T": "2023-10-05T04:00:00Z"
  }
]
```

The first object in the list where `Action.Charge` is nonzero has been updated with the new value.

Comment: Please provide input and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse to each path of interest, and use `|=` to update them based on their current value. For this, you can use your `if` expression to distiguish the cases (note that since jq 1.7 the default `else .` branch can be omitted):

```bash
.[].Action.Charge |= if . > 0 then 34 end
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zGtHQnYubhh)

Alternatively, you could also pre-filter the paths of interest using `select` on the LHS (note the added parentheses), and just assign the new value to them (using `=` as there is no dependecy on the previous value anymore):

```bash
(.[].Action.Charge | select(. > 0)) = 34
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-okKbyMVUil)

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Action": {
      "Charge": 34,
      "Discharge": 100
    },
    "T": "2023-10-05T01:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "Action": {
      "Charge": 0,
      "Discharge": 22
    },
    "T": "2023-10-05T04:00:00Z"
  }
]
```

If you want to provide the new value from the command line, use the `--argjson` flag for JSON values (like a number), or the `--arg` flag for raw strings:

```bash
jq --argjson val 34 '.[].Action.Charge |= if . > 0 then $val end'
# or
jq --argjson val 34 '(.[].Action.Charge | select(. > 0)) = $val'
```

Comment: This does not work on the commane line: `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1...`

Comment: @RichardBarraclough Maybe you missed including the `else .` branch if you are using an older (1.6 or less) version of jq?